# How to implement indeterminate Progressbar in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

My application has some time-consuming background processes to be run occasionally. I want to show that the application is working using a simple **indeterminate** `ttk.Progressbar`.
However, my implementation only shows static progress bar.

Anyway, here is how I implemented it.

```
class MyApp(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        fname = 'test.txt'
        self.build_ui()
        self.process_file(fname)

    def process_file(self, fname):
        self.show_progress(True)
        fdata = self.read_file(fname)
        fdata = self.spellcheck(fdata)
        self.show_progress(False)
        return fdata

    def show_progress(self, start)
        if start:
            self.prog_win = tk.Toplevel()
            self.prog_win.title('Working...')
            self.prog_win.resizable(0, 0)
            self.progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self.prog_win,
                                                orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
                                                mode='indeterminate',
                                                takefocus=True)
            self.progress_bar.grid()
            self.progress_bar.start()
        else:
            self.progress_bar.stop()
            self.prog_win.destroy()


root = tk.Tk()
root.update()
gui = MyApp(root)
gui.mainloop()
```

The code above does not work as intended. The `Progressbar` appears static, it does not move and just hangs there forever. I tried to use threading but if I start `show_progress` in a separate `Thread` it always gets executed after the processing has been done.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `MyApp.mainloop`? Call `root.mainloop()`.

Comment: You need to boil it down to the minimal example that makes it fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `self.read_file()` and `self.spellcheck()` are blocking which prevents Tkinter from updating your progress bar in its main loop. A simple way to solve this is to do your processing in a separate thread, and periodically check to see if the thread finished its work.

```
import threading

class MyApp(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        fname = 'test.txt'
        self.build_ui()
        self.process_file(fname)

    def process_file(self, fname):
        self.show_progress(True)

        # Start thread to process file.
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.process_file_worker, args=(fname,))
        self.thread.daemon = True # Allow the program to terminate without waiting for the thread to finish.
        self.thread.start()

        # Start checking the thread.
        self.process_file_check()

    def process_file_check(self):
        if self.thread.is_alive():
            # Thread is still running, check thread again in 10 milliseconds.
            self.after(10, self.process_file_check)

        else:
            # Thread finished, handle processed results.
            # Do something with `self.fdata`.
            self.show_progress(False)

    def process_file_worker(self, fname):
        # This is run inside the thread.
        fdata = self.read_file(fname)
        fdata = self.spellcheck(fdata)
        self.fdata = fdata

    def show_progress(self, start):
        if start:
            self.prog_win = tk.Toplevel()
            self.prog_win.title('Working...')
            self.prog_win.resizable(0, 0)
            self.progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self.prog_win,
                                                orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
                                                mode='indeterminate',
                                                takefocus=True)
            self.progress_bar.grid()
            self.progress_bar.start()
        else:
            self.progress_bar.stop()
            self.prog_win.destroy()


root = tk.Tk()
root.update()
gui = MyApp(root)
gui.mainloop()
```